# Cursor не находит значения

Tags: java, android, cursor

Реализация вроде, как всегда, типовая, но курсор упорно не хочет находить данные по регистрации щелчка по элементу. Передает корректную position (с 0 и выше для элементов списка) и дальше просто находит 0 элементов. База инициализирована и корректно заполнена. Подскажите, в чем может быть ошибка?

```
listViewPasswords.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            Bundle tempBundle = new Bundle();

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View v, int position, long id) {       //брать Position для идентификации номера пароля!
                DialogFragment dialogShowPass = new DetailedPassFragment();                 //инициализируем фрагмент ShowPass

                PasswordDatabaseHelper helper = new PasswordDatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                SQLiteDatabase dbShowPass = helper.getReadableDatabase();
                Cursor cursorShowPass = dbShowPass.query("DATAPASS",
                        new String[]{"SITE", "PASS", "INFO"},
                        "_id = ?",
                        new String[]{Integer.toString(position)},
                        null, null, null);

                if(cursorShowPass.moveToFirst()) {
                    tempBundle.putString("site", cursorShowPass.getString(0));
                    tempBundle.putString("pass", cursorShowPass.getString(1));
                    tempBundle.putString("info", cursorShowPass.getString(2));

                    dialogShowPass.setArguments(tempBundle);
                    dialogShowPass.show(getFragmentManager(), "editPass");
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data not send into Bundle"+" "+cursorShowPass.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: У вас захардкожены параметры запросов. Могут быть опечатки. Вы не пересоздали бд после изменения структуры. У вас инстант ран включен и изменения в коде не заливаются на девайс или ещё много разных причин

Comment: Параметры вынес в константы на записи и чтении. О каком пересоздании из-за структуры идёт речь? После добавления элементов, они появляются в списке через SimpleCursorAdapter (а вот этот курсор работает), и все идет нормально, пока не доходит до данного проблемного курсора. Инстант ран отключил. Все также, ничего не поменялось

Comment: Вот попробуйте здесь посмотреть свою БД.  Там можно сразу sql запрос выполнить, который вам нужен  https://github.com/pavel163/ProbeTools

Comment: Вы уверены, что `_id` соответствует позиции в списке?

Comment: Eugene Krivenja Вы правы. Надо смотреть на long id, хоть он и странные значения выдает, но нормальные ссылки дает. И вынес реализацию поиска в основной поток. Понимаю, не очень идея, но если подкинете идею, как реализовать передачу результатов асинхронного потока в отрисованный Dialog, буду очень благодарен